# Export CSV in powershell with Domain name in title

Tags: powershell, csv, dns, export

We are performing an audit of different networks and need to distinguish between domains. The code I currently use will export to .csv but just uses the title I choose. What I need is for it to automatically name the .csv file with the domain name in it.

Below is my current code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADObject -filter 'objectclass -eq "user"' -properties CN,DisplayName,Discription | select | export-csv -NoTypeInformation "c:\ADUsers.csv"
```

Comment: did you do some research on your own? this shouldnt be too hard to figure out... you can get the domain name with `(gwmi win32_computersystem).domain` just put it in a variable and use it in your export-csv statement

Answer (score 1):

Did you want just the current domain, or the domain with parent domains included?

Current Domain Name:

```powershell
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$name = Get-ADDomain | Select -ExpandProperty NetBIOSName
Get-ADObject -Filter 'objectclass -eq "user"' -Properties CN,DisplayName,Discription | select |  
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "c:\" + $name + ".csv"
```

Comment: One small oversight: the **Import-Module** statement needs to come before the **Get-ADDomain** statement.